# PHP str_replace Replacing Two words

Tags: php, str-replace

My code is below..

```
echo $type = str_replace(array('q','h','f'),array('Quarter','Half','Full'),$_POST['type']);
```

here on the above line $_POST['type'] have These 3 values;

1. $_POST type = 'q'
2. $_POST type = 'h'
3. $_POST type = 'f'

I want to replace

- q with Quarter
- h with Half
- f with Full.

My Problem is when $_POST['type']='h',

The result of above code means value of $type came **HalFull**.

Why this is happening...

Is there any solution for this...?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just change the order slightly? If you did the replacements in the order 'q', 'f', 'h', then I think you'd be fine, as 'Full' doesn't have an 'h' in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it is replacing `h` with `Half` and then the last `f` of `Half` with `Full`

May be if you can provide a regexp that only replaces if the source string is exactly one character, then it would work.

Try this:

```php
echo $type = preg_replace(array('/^q$/i','/^h$/i','/^f$/i'),array('Quarter','Half','Full'),$_POST['type']);
```

It works

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

`str_replace` is executed consecutively for each of the three parameters.

For the first parameter, nothing is replaced.

For the second parameter, `h` is replaced by `Half`.

For the second parameter, the `f` of `Half` is replaced by `Full`.

So you end up with `HalFull`.

---

#### The solution

There's many approaches to tackle this issue.

The simplest solution would be to use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead, and refine your search criteria :

```
echo $type = preg_replace(array('/^q/i','/^h/i','/^f/i'),array('Quarter','Half','Full'),'h');
```

Comment: no no no sir... I want only Half when $_POST['type'] = 'h', I'm getting HalFull. I just want Half

Comment: @GyandeepSharma : I added a solution to my answer

Comment: or just use a basic if else

Answer (score 1):

If you change the order of replacements, you'll be fine:

```
echo $type = str_replace(array('q','f','h'),array('Quarter','Full','Half'),$_POST['type']);
```

..because 'f' produces 'Full', and 'Full' doesn't have any 'h's in, so the next replacement is safe.

Or you could perhaps choose a completely different approach, which would be safer, and I dare say a little more readable and maintainable.

```
$translate = array(
  'q' => 'Quarter',
  'h' => 'Half',
  'f' => 'Full'
);

echo $type = $translate[$_POST['type']];
```